# How to make any random numbers and letters get printed at once and change everytime you re-run the code?

Tags: python, random

How  to make any random numbers and letters get printed at once and change every time you re-run the code? e.g 0asd84hqe98asd8 Thanks

Comment: Have you found `java.util.Random()`? Have you tried anything? What code or idea do you have so far? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: use the random modules and mayhbe random.choice()

Comment: I havent started yet, but i havent tried a number / letter generator before... I have used RandInt before but only to print 1 integer 1-3. i have an idea how to make this generator but trying to use something simple than doing concatenation

Comment: You haven't started yet? So you're expecting someone to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import letters, digits, lowercase
from random import choice


def random_string(n):
    return ''.join([choice(digits + letters) for i in range(n)])


print random_string(15)
```

`letters` includes both cases. if you are only interested in getting lowercase,
change `letters` in the function to `lowercase`.

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is use an array to hold values then random number for index and then loop it however many times u want there is probly a better way and I haven't put code as on bus right now(on phone) so wouldn't be able to test it